# Updating polygon areas in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, area

I'm using QGIS 2.6 and regularly update a shapefile layer to indicate felling progress. However, if I edit the nodes of a polygon, save the layer out then look at the Attributes table the area shown doesn't change.

Comment: Shapefiles don't support automatic updating of the/an area field. Some formats do, such as an Esri file geodatabase. You must manually recalculate the area any time you make changes. Joseph points out you can use a virtual field, but as noted that's only in a QGIS project file (similar to an ArcGIS mxd) - it's not actually part of the data. What you really need to do if distributing the shapefile is re-run that $area field calculation on your area field each time you revise the file.

Comment: You can achieve it using the [AutoFields plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/). Watch [this video](https://vimeo.com/178761887) for an example of auto-updating geometric properties. In your case, you would just need a field and to choose Area in the expression options of the plugin's interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a **Virtual** field which updates features automatically based on the expression you insert. So in your case, it would be:

```
$area
```

[image: Field Calculator for virtual field]

You will need to create a *Project* for the shapefile (if you haven't done so already) as virtual fields are stored in the project files (.qgs).

Answer (score 1):

The identify tool provides a quick way to access area measurements. You can change the units by going to:

> > Project menu > Project Properties | General > Measurements

[image]

WARNING:
Sometimes area calculated in QGIS is wildly inaccurate. This can happen regardless of whether you use the identify tool or the field calculator in the attribute table. It's usually a result of having multiple layers with different coordinate reference systems in the same project. If you start seeing area numbers that don't make sense, try loading the layer into a blank project, turn off on-the-fly reprojection, and redo the calculation using field calculator.