# Making polygon layers always have area fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon, qgis-modeler, delaunay

I am making Delaunay triangles of several (over 40) combinations of points and it is very tedious to output new shapefiles for each combination without even having the area of the triangles by default, which is what I am most interested in.

Is there a way to make an area field by default for all new polygons and besides can I use tools like Delaunay triangulation to add new polygons to one shapefile without having to make new shapefiles each time?

Comment: One question at a time please, otherwise this website becomes a mess ;)

Comment: Would a Python answer satisfy you?

Comment: What do you  mean by "several combination of points"? Do you  have several point shapefiles or do you use several combination of points in one shapefile?

Comment: If you output them to an existing shapefile perhaps you could use a virtual field or the Autofields plugin to have their areas calculated.  I haven't used either but I remembered seeing the virtual field discussion.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154480/updating-polygon-areas-in-qgis

Answer (score 6):

To propose another method that does not imply any coding: you can create a model. That's probably easier to understand if you are not used to Python. You can however export the Model created in this way as a Python script.

Go to `Menu Processing / Graphical Modeler…` to create a new model.

1. From the input tab, select Vector features and give it a name, let's say Input points.
2. Go to the `algorithm tab`, search and add `Delaunay Triangulation`, name it and as input layer, change the symbol on the left to `Model Input` (the symbol with the three gear wheels) and select the layer `Input points` from 1, see:

[image]

3. Again in the `algorithm tab` look for field calculator in fill in the fields accordingly, see screenshot. On the bottom, you see the expression used `$area` - you can change this to whatever expression you want to use like `area($geometry)`:

[image]

4. Your Model now should look like on the next screenshot. Save it to your project or somewhere on your machine:

[image]

5. You can now run the model in batch mode (as described in the solution by @MrXsquared), choosing all points layer you have as input. It will create a new output with delaunay triangles, including a field for the area.

See here for one possibility to automatically select several files at once: use autofill, define a file pattern (just *.gpkg if you want to select all Geopackage files in a folder), select the folder, press find files and you see a preview of the files found. You can add them pressing OK.

[image]

6. Just to see and compare with the solution by @BERA, I exported my model as Python script - this is what I get:

```
    """
    Model exported as python.
    Name : fi
    Group : 
    With QGIS : 31600
    """
    
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
    import processing
    
    
    class Fi(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    
        def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
            self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource('InputPoints', 'Input Points', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
            self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('_out', '_out', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))
    
        def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
            # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
            # overall progress through the model
            feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
            results = {}
            outputs = {}
    
            # Delaunay-Triangulation
            alg_params = {
                'INPUT': parameters['InputPoints'],
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            }
            outputs['Delaunaytriangulation'] = processing.run('qgis:delaunaytriangulation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    
            feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                return {}
    
            # Feldrechner
            alg_params = {
                'FIELD_LENGTH': 20,
                'FIELD_NAME': 'area',
                'FIELD_PRECISION': 10,
                'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
                'FORMULA': '$area',
                'INPUT': outputs['Delaunaytriangulation']['OUTPUT'],
                'OUTPUT': parameters['_out']
            }
            outputs['Feldrechner'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
            results['_out'] = outputs['Feldrechner']['OUTPUT']
            return results
    
        def name(self):
            return 'fi'
    
        def displayName(self):
            return 'fi'
    
        def group(self):
            return ''
    
        def groupId(self):
            return ''
    
        def createInstance(self):
            return Fi()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use pyqgis. Script below will add and calculate a field named `area`. If you have many layers it is possible to modify the code and process all at once. You will have to rerun the area calculation if you edit/modify the polygons, so it is not fully automatic.

```py
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Delaunay triangulation')[0] #Change to match your layername
newFieldName = 'area' #Name of new field that is created and calculated

#Add a field. Skip this part if you are recalculating area
pr = lyr.dataProvider()
newfield = QgsField(name=newFieldName, type=6)
pr.addAttributes([newfield])
lyr.updateFields()

#Calculate area
fieldindex = lyr.fields().indexFromName(newFieldName) #Find index of new field
attrMap = {f.id() : {fieldindex : round(f.geometry().area(), 2)} for f in lyr.getFeatures()} #Dictionary of dictionaries: {feature id : {fieldindex : geometry area}, ... }
lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attrMap) #Update all features/rows with area
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

By default I don't know, must be at least a little more complicated if possible I guess.

But you can run "Add geometry attributes" as a batch process and apply it on all your files. Start it from processing toolbox and click on "Run as batch":

[image]

Here you can then add your files / layers. Depending on your QGIS Version very convenient by adding whole folders, files starting with a special character, all open files, ...