# Creating Multiple Instances of Measure Line

Tags: qgis, line, area, measurements

[image]I'm trying to use multiple instances of the Measure Line and Area at the same time. More specifically, I need to measure setbacks from lot lines. The way Measure Line is set up, it becomes quite a mess seeing the lines connected together. Is it possible to create two points, right click and add a new measurement without the initial measurement disappearing? Any alternative plugins that could make this work?

Thanks for any suggestions!

I'd like to create two separate instances of this simultaneously instead of the first instance disappearing after you use the right click to complete the end point.

Comment: A screenshot (and maybe other details) could help

Comment: Maybe you could use a line-feature instead with a dynamic field that has the lenght. You could then have a label from this lenght-field. In this way you could create as many lines as you want and they would remain. See here for a similar example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154480/updating-polygon-areas-in-qgis

Comment: Or label with `$length`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a memory line layer (using the create  new temporary scratch layer) and style this layer with either the ["Measure Line" style](https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/5/) from Klas Karlsson or the ["Distance Measurement Styles"](https://github.com/faunalia/QGIS-Resources) from Faunalia (also accessible from the ressource sharing plugin).

Both are slightly different but each one could be modified to fit your needs

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Am I correct in saying that the "Measure Line" style does not work well with rectangles? Also, I am looking to get the area measurement. With Distance Measurement Styles, I am able to do this, however the measurement is stuck on millimeters... Even when I set Distance Measurement Styles to the map default it stays in millimeters and changes length when I dependent on the Scale of the project. Not sure if its possible to change this. Also, is there no way to view the measurements in real time as well? Thanks for your help!